# C#: Azure.Data.Tables shows that I can use CreateQueryFilter, but it is not being recognized by VS2022 intellisense

Tags: c#, azure, asp.net-core, azure.data.tables

I can successfully create a Azure.Data.Tables.TableClient. I am using Azure.Data.Tables version 12.8.0, and the [documentation clearly states the method CreateQueryFilter is available to me](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.data.tables.tableclient?view=azure-dotnet#methods). However, I am not able to use it in my code (.Net 7). My tableClient object operates fine as I can QueryAsync, etc. I also viewed the TableClient definition via source link, and I see the method present.

Any clue why this will not appear for me?

Comment: Could you please share the code where you are trying to use `CreateQueryFilter`.

Comment: Iam able to see the `CreateQueryFilter` ,[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2N4wc.png).Is this what you are looking for?

Comment: Hi, do you think [this blog](https://code-maze.com/azure-table-storage-aspnetcore/) could help you? I think you might need a sample. could you pls let us know which database you wanna to connect? Azure CosmosDb?